# KOMAoptions{headsepline = true, footsepline = true} change geometry settings

Tags: header-footer, pdftex, margins, koma-script, geometry

I am using tex(-based techniques) for the first time. Currently I am writing my doctoral thesis via **pdflatex** and encounter an annoying problem:

My university predetermines very **strict page geometry properties** and I was able to implement them via the **geometry package**. So far so good. I'm using **KOMA-script class** **scrbook** and when I add **header- and footerseplines** (for decorative purposes), the **geometry is dramatically changed**. I used the layout package to show the layout and its values.

The head-/footseplines are optional, so I could just remove them, but maybe somebody knows how to fix this problem? I would really appreciate it. **Thank you!**

Below is my minimal working example:

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[12pt, BCOR=0mm, oneside, headings=small, openany, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, captions=tableheading]{scrbook}
%Fonts % Babel
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
%Lipsum for dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum} 
%Layout package for page layout
\usepackage{layout} 
%
%geometry package
\usepackage[ paper=a4paper, layout=a4paper, top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, marginparsep=5mm, marginparwidth=20mm, head=12.5mm, foot=12.5mm pdftex]{geometry}
%
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Adding headsep- and footsepline makes trouble
\KOMAoptions{headsepline = true, footsepline = true}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
%
%Begin document
\begin{document}
%Dummy text
\lipsum
%Show layout
\layout 
%End document
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug regarding the option `footsepline` in KOMA-Script version 3.12 and 3.13, see [www.komascript.de/release3.13](http://www.komascript.de/release3.13) (German). Update your KOMA-Script to version 3.15.

If that is not possible - for example [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) still uses version 3.12 - change the order in your preambel to

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Adding headsep- and footsepline makes trouble
\KOMAoptions{headsepline = true, footsepline = true}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%geometry package
\usepackage[ paper=a4paper, layout=a4paper, top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, marginparsep=5mm, marginparwidth=20mm, head=12.5mm, foot=12.5mm]{geometry}
```

Or use `headsepline` and `footsepline` as class options

```
\documentclass[...,headsepline,footsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage[...]{geometry}
```

Note, there is a command `\KOMAScriptVersion` to print the used version number in the document.

Additionally there is a missing comma between the `geometry` options `foot=12.5mm` and `pdftex`  in your MWE. Note, that you can remove `pdftex` because this option is not needed anyway.

Comment: To me it compiled fine, so I thought the only problem was that “bad option” to `geometry` if you add a comment about the “wrong option” I will delete my answer, since yours actually answers teh question.

Comment: @Manuel I have added the comment.

Comment: Ah ok I see. Upgraded to newest KOMA-script version 3.15.1910 and it worked like a charm. why didn't I think of doing that :D 
Thank you very much for the quick help! 

now do I have to close this thread or does it close automatically?